# C# How to: 2d array of jagged arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I want to make a multidemesional array of jagged arrays. Is this possible? How?

For Instance I see lokts of examples like the following:

```
int[][,] jaggedArray4 = new int[3][,]
```

I want to create the following:

```
int[,,][] myFixedJagged = new int[2,2,3][]
```

where the last [] is Jagged. How can I declare that?

Thanks!

Comment: Why asking? Try and see.

Comment: I can't seem to get it declared...

Comment: I know... Just making the title common.

Comment: Jagged array is no more than an array of array elements. Your declaration creates multidimensional array of single dimensional array elements. If you want array element to be jagged array, use `int[,,][][] myFixedJagged = new int[2,2,3][][];`

Answer (score 2):

This just works:

```
int[,,][] myFixedJagged = new int[2, 2, 3][];
myFixedJagged[0, 0, 0] = new int[10];
myFixedJagged[0, 0, 0][9] = 1;
```

I wouldn't want to use it though.

Comment: Exactly. Note that in C# an array `int[,,][]` is a three-dimensional array whose element type is `int[]`, a one-dimensional array of ints. The brackets are written in the opposite order by the runtime. For example `myFixedJagged.GetType().ToString()` or equivalently `typeof(int[,,][]).ToString()` gives something like `"System.Int32[][,,]"` where `Int32[]` is an array type which is the element type of the "outer" (in CLR notation) array.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // This is the silliest thing I have seen in my life
    int[, ,][][] jgarray=new int[2, 2, 3][][];

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
            for (int k=0; k<3; k++)
            {
                var array =new int[10][];

                for (int z=0; z<10; z++)
                {
                    array[z]=new int[20];
                    for (int v=0; v<20; v++)
                    {
                        array[z][v]=v+20*(z+10*(k+3*(j+2*i)));
                    }
                }

                jgarray[i, j, k]=array;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: pic]